# Algorithm to test if a variety is rational

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, function-fields

Is there an algorithm to test if a variety is rational? Equivalently, is there an algorithm to test if a field extension is purely transcendental?

I could not find anything in the book by Cox-Little-O'Shea and basic search turned up nothing. Given how little we know about the Cremona group, I suspect that the algorithm might not be known, but I want to confirm.

Comment: There is probably no algorithm for testing if a variety is rational.  However, assuming one open conjecture of David Mumford, there is an algorithm for testing if a complex projective manifold is rationally connected (though not a particularly fast algorithm).  I heard this algorithm in a lecture of Bjorn Poonen: alternatively compute for each degree $e$ whether the Chow variety / Hilbert scheme / Hom space of rational curves of degree $e$ dominates your variety and compute whether each vector space $H^0(X,\Omega_{X/\mathbb{C}}^{\otimes (e+1)})$ is nonzero.

Comment: If there was such an algorithm, it could presumably decide whether for instance the cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^6$ given by $\sum X_i^3=0$ is rational -- a question which is wide open.